# Comparing and appending .csv files in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have 2 .csv files which I want to compare and append. Let's say there are numbers in column 1 file 1. I have a similar set of numbers in column 1 file 2 -- but in a different order and not all are present. 
I want to search through file 1 column 1 to see if there is a match for the number in column 1 file 2. If there is a match, I want to append the information from file 2 into file 1 by adding the columns to the matched number. 
I also get rid of any blank lines in the input file.

For example:

```
File 1
Number Name     EmailAddress
1      Jenny    jj@ymail.com
2      Josh     jh@ymail.com
3      Tony     ty@gmail.org
4      Jeff     jf@youtube.cc


File2
Number Address  
4      123 Walnut St

1      17 Yerlington Wy
7      420 St B


Output File
Number Name  EmailAddress     Address
4      Jeff  jf@youtube.cc    123 Walnut St
1      Jenny jj@ymail.com     17 Yerlington Wy
7      NO ENTRY
```

Here's the code I have so far, which seems to do everything but append the correct information.

```
import csv

f1 = file('inFile.csv', 'rb')
f2 = file('inFile2', 'rb')
f3 = file('outFile.csv', 'wb')

c1 = csv.reader(f1)
c2 = csv.reader(f2)
c3 = csv.writer(f3)

masterlist = [row for row in c2]
for hosts_row in c1:
    row = 1
    found = False
    for master_row in masterlist:
        results_row = hosts_row
        end_row = masterlist
        if any(hosts_row):
            if hosts_row[0] == master_row[0]:
                results_row.append(end_row[row][1])
                found = True
                break

            if not found:
                results_row.append('NO ENTRY')

    if any(hosts_row):
        c3.writerow(results_row)

f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
```

Comment: are the columns separated by space or tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't have separator in your csv files, I had to rewrite them like this (comma separator):

inFile.csv:

```
Number,Name,EmailAddress
1,Jenny,jj@ymail.com
2,Josh,jh@ymail.com
3,Tony,ty@gmail.org
4,Jeff,jf@youtube.cc
```

inFile2.csv:

```
Number,Address  
4,123 Walnut St

1,17 Yerlington Wy
7,420 St B
```

Then you have few problems in your code:

- you are missing the check for empty master_row
- strange variable end_row is doing something you don't want and is practically useless as you really want to append `master_row[1]`
- condition for `not found` is in wrong block, so 'NO ENTRY' is appended multiple times
- there is unused variable `row`
- (just enhancement) python will close files for you when their variables comes out of scope, so you can remove close() calls

After my fixes:

```
import csv

f1 = file('inFile.csv', 'rb')
f2 = file('inFile2.csv', 'rb')
f3 = file('outFile.csv', 'wb')

c1 = csv.reader(f1)
c2 = csv.reader(f2)
c3 = csv.writer(f3)

masterlist = [row for row in c2]
for hosts_row in c1:
    found = False
    for master_row in masterlist:
        results_row = hosts_row
        if hosts_row and master_row:
            if hosts_row[0] == master_row[0]:
                results_row.append(master_row[1])
                found = True
                break

    if not found:
        results_row.append('NO ENTRY')

    if any(hosts_row):
        c3.writerow(results_row)
```

output file:

```
Number,Name,EmailAddress,Address  
1,Jenny,jj@ymail.com,17 Yerlington Wy
2,Josh,jh@ymail.com,NO ENTRY
3,Tony,ty@gmail.org,NO ENTRY
4,Jeff,jf@youtube.cc,123 Walnut St
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your input! I realized there were a few bugs after posting, so thank you for pointing those out.

But when I use your code, for some reason instead of the correct addresses, all addresses come out as address or NO ENTRY. I'm only getting the title to show and not the correct unit. Any insight?

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, it works for me (produces the "output file" I pasted). The address is appended on line `results_row.append(master_row[1])` so maybe try to print "master_row" and "master_row[1]" before it to see what is really happening.

Comment: Thanks again. Actually, this time it was the file itself that had been corrupted on my computer! When I re-saved the file, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Another take on it (this one produces the output you presented, but I suppose Tomás' output is what you described):

```
import csv

def read_file(path):
    with open(path) as fh:
        data = csv.reader(fh)
        return [row for row in data if row]

def match(l1, l2):
    result = []
    for i in l2:
        match = False
        for j in l1:
            if i[0] == j[0]:
                row = j + i[1:]
                match = True
                break
        if not match:
            row = [i[0], "NO ENTRY"]
        result.append(row)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l1 = read_file("inFile.csv")
    l2 = read_file("inFile2")
    result = match(l1, l2)
    of = open('outFile.csv', 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(of)
    writer.writerows(result)
    of.close()
```

A couple of notes:

You should use `open` instead of `file`; in the file mode, `b` is for binary files (by opening in text mode conversions of line terminations can be made). There were more, but they have been addressed already.